# non integrability of stopping time in martingales

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

i need some help with stopping time and martingales:

let $M=(M_n)_n\ge0$ a martingale such that $0<a<|M_n-M_n-1|\le K$, and let $T$ be a stopping time $T=\inf\{n:M_n>\lambda\}$, how can i demonstrate that T is not integrable?

I have to demonstrate that using Doob theorem, in particular i already showed that if $\tau$ was integrable $M^{\tau}$ is uniformly integrable (which is point 1 of the exercise), but i can't understand how to go on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $T$ were integrable, since $|M_n - M_{n-1}| \leq K$, the conditions for Doob's optional stopping theorem would be satisfied. What does this tell you about $E(M_T)$ and how does it compare to $E(M_0)$?

Comment: in this case $E(M_T)=E(M_0)$. Considering $M_0=0$, how can i demonstrate that $E(M_T)\neq0$ ?

Comment: Use the definition of $T$ to find a lower bound for $M_T$.